# ERROR: repository x not found: does not exist or no pull access

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm getting the below error message when doing a `docker-compose up`:

```
ERROR: repository phusionphp not found: does not exist or no pull access
```

However I have built this image with `docker build -t phusionphp:7.0 .`

I am able to run this directly using `sudo docker run -it --rm phusionphp:7.0`:

```
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh...
*** Running /etc/rc.local...
*** Booting runit daemon...
*** Runit started as PID 9
Jun 16 12:00:57 a62ea0266f66 syslog-ng[15]: syslog-ng starting up; version='3.5.6'
ls
^C*** Shutting down runit daemon (PID 9)...
*** Killing all processes...
```

**docker-compose.yaml**:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  php:
      image: phusionphp:7
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
      volumes:
        - ./data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
      links:
        - mysql
  apache:
      image: phusionapache
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
      links:
        - php
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: "example"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "example"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "example"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "example"
```

Seems I have the images present, `sudo docker images`:

```
customlamp/phusionphp                           latest                    65221e392f1f        17 minutes ago      317MB
phusionphp                                      7.0                       65221e392f1f        17 minutes ago      317MB
phusionphp                                      5.6                       488fda307f61        27 minutes ago      317MB
phusionphp                                      latest                    488fda307f61        27 minutes ago      317MB
customlamp/phusionphp                           5.6                       488fda307f61        27 minutes ago      317MB
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have image `phusionphp:7.0`

So reference it with the whole tag `7.0` or without the tag to use latest.
Don't reference it just with `7` as tag.

So `image: phusionphp:7.0`

or `image: phusionphp`

instead of

```
image: phusionphp:7
```